# Adding hamburger menu to multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-mvXKKoSCU&t=313s&ab_channel=CodeSpot tutorial on adding in a hamburger menu. Works well on the INDEX.html page but when I add the same code to the other pages such as "contact" "about" none of the menu features work.

I know I'm doing something wrong but is only week 1 of learning how to code

Comment: Make sure you're referencing the correct styles (CSS) and scripts (JS). If your other pages are within a folder and you are using relative paths (like `/myscript.js`), you will need to update those paths to point to the original place (e.g. being one folder deep `/../myscript.js`)

Comment: Tried doing a complete copy past of index.html to my about me page - still nothing. Will copy the code across to make it easier

Comment: Are both files in the exact same folder?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Rylee you are a legend - site files were located in a sub folder called "pages", once i moved them out into the main website folder it then began working.

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have a folder structure like this

```
IamRootFolder
    index1.html
    IamFolder
        index2.html
    IamFolderToo
        index2.html
        css.css
```

There are three ways to define a path (for what i know)

```
/the-root-folder
./this-folder
../the-previous-folder
```

And not adding anything is the same as `./`.
so to access `css.css`
index1.html will need `./IamFolderToo/css.css`
index2.html will need `../IamFolderToo/css.css`
index3.html will need `./css.css`

Otherwise they can all simply use `/IamFolderToo/css.css`.
[W3 examples link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)